# "Unanswered" filter text is clipped a bit

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Small cosmetic bug: When selecting either of the "Unanswered" question filters on the Android app, the last letter of of `Unanswered` is slightly clipped:

[image]

This is on a Nexus 4 running Android 4.2.2 (CyanogenMod 10.1).

Comment: Repro Galaxy S4 running 4.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have resized the unanswered dropdown and fixed the alignment of the search questions bar when Unanswered (newest) is selected.  It will make it out in the next update.